# WSDL not valid in Jmeter

Tags: apache, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am testing Web Service using Apache JMeter ( V2.5.1 )
while loading I am getting below error.

**The WSDL was not valid , please double check the url. org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.WSDLException:www.webservicex.net**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dplh.jpg)

same wsdl worked in soapUI : 
webservice URL : http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 0):

Paste Following SOAP request code into "**SOAP/XML-RPC Request**” sampler in  "**SOAP/XML-RPC Data**" section and In **URL** enter "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL"

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webservicex.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetGeoIP>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:IPAddress>192.168.1.1</web:IPAddress>
      </web:GetGeoIP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Click on **Run** button. After execution you can see response in “**View Result Tree**” as below.

[image]